# How to solve this php error(Object of class CI_DB_mysql_result could not be converted to int)

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am developing an application on Codeigniter and trying to implement a search function from my database tables. I am stuck with these 3 errors/warnings.

```
1.(A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined index: prtc_search
Filename: controllers/form.php
Line Number: 818)

2.(A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined index: prtc_search
Filename: controllers/form.php
Line Number: 818)

3.(A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Object of class CI_DB_mysql_result could not be converted to int
Filename: views/prtc_search.php
Line Number: 2)
```

I am using the same codes to search data from other database tables and it works fine with no errors or warnings, but the same code is not working when it comes to this particular page. I am stuck on this will be grateful if someone could kindly give me clues or solutions on this. Below is the codes for the search page.

```
//view.php
<?php 
        if ($result==1)
        {
            echo "NO DATA FOUND";
        }
        else
        {?>
    <div class="table">
        <div class="table_header">Edit from the following List of PRTC</div>
        <table >
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Country</th>
                <th>Dzongkhag</th>
                <th>Geog</th>
                <th>Village</th>
                <th>Address</th>                
                <th style="color:#FF2525;width:4%;">Edit</th>
            </tr>
        <?php   

                        $i=0;
            foreach($result as $row)
            {
                ?>
                <tr <?php /*if($i%2==0) echo 'style="background-color:#F2DEDE";'; else echo 'style="background-color:#D9EDF7";'; $i++;*/?>>
                    <td style="vertical-align:middle;"><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
                    <td style="vertical-align:middle;"><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
                    <td style="vertical-align:middle;"><?php echo $row['country']; ?></td>
                    <td style="vertical-align:middle;"><?php echo $row['dzongkhag']; ?></td>
                    <td style="vertical-align:middle;"><?php echo $row['geog']; ?></td>
                    <td style="vertical-align:middle;"><?php echo $row['village']; ?></td>
                    <td style="vertical-align:middle;"><?php echo $row['address']; ?></td>                  
                    <td style="ertical-align:middle;">
                    <a href = "<?php echo base_url().'form/prtc_one/'.$row['id']; ?>">
                    <img src="<?php echo base_url();?>images/edit.png" title="Edit"></a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <?php
            } 
        }
        ?>

        </table>
        </div>
    </div> 
<!-- <a style="margin-left:2%;margin-top:20%;" href="<?php echo site_url('form/search_expo/'.$searchquery);?>">Export This..<img style="margin:0 !important;" src="<?php echo site_url('images/b_export.png')?>"></a> -->
```

Controller

```
//controller
function prtc_one($id)
    {

        $session_user=$this->session->userdata('logged_in');
        if($session_user['ath']=='admin')
        {           
            $data['result']         = $this->search_model->get_prtc_one($id);
            $data['session_user']   = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
            $datah['title']         = "Sasec | PRTC Edit"; //For Title

                $this->load->view('includes/header',$datah);
                $this->load->view('includes/leftmenu',$data);
                $this->load->view('includes/flag',$data);

                $this->load->view('prtc_edit',$data);

                $this->load->view('includes/footer');
        }   
        else
            {
            echo ' <script type="text/javascript">
                        alert("Access Error....");
                        </script>';
                redirect('login/home');
            }
    }
```

Model

```
//model
    function get_prtc_one($id)
        {
            $query=$this->db->get_where('prtc_info',array('id' => $id));
            $query=$query->row_array();
            return $query;
```

Database query

```
function prtc_search($searchquery)
    {
        $count = 0;

        //Search using id
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->order_by('name ASC');
        $this->db->where("id LIKE '%$searchquery%'");
        $result = $this->db->get('prtc_info');
        if ($result->num_rows() > 0)
        {
            $row = $result->result_array();
            $count = 1;
            return $result;
        }
```

Your advice or solutions will be greatly appreciated. Thank You
 controller

```
function prtc_search()
    {
        $session_user=$this->session->userdata('logged_in');
        if($session_user['ath']=='admin')
        {

            $list['result'] = $this->search_model->prtc_search($_POST['prtc_search']);
            $list['searchquery']=$_POST['prtc_search'];

            $data['session_user']   = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
            $datah['title']         = "Sasec | PRTC Search"; //For Title

                    $this->load->view('includes/header',$datah);
                    $this->load->view('includes/leftmenu',$data);
                    $this->load->view('includes/flag',$data);

                    $this->load->view('prtc_search',$list);

                    $this->load->view('includes/footer');
        }
        else{
            echo ' <script type="text/javascript">
                        alert("Access Error....");
                        </script>';
                redirect('login/home');
            }

    }
```

Comment: From where you call `prtc_search($searchquery)` function in your code??

Comment: I have added the code @ stay. Sorry I was away from the internet

Comment: now what error you got??

Comment: i used isset() in prtc_search(). The if(isset()) results to false and it redirects me to the login/home page.`else{
            echo ' <script type="text/javascript">
                        alert("Access Error....");
                        </script>';
                redirect('login/home');
            }
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct your query with

```
function prtc_search($searchquery) {
    $count = 0;
    //Search using id
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->like('id', $searchquery);
    $this->db->order_by("name", "asc");
    $result = $this->db->get('prtc_info');
    if ($result->num_rows() > 0) {
        $row = $result->result_array();
        $count = 1;
        return $row;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Also change this model query

```
function get_prtc_one($id) {
    $query = $this->db->get_where('prtc_info', array('id' => $id));

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        $result  = $query->row_array();
        return $result;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }

}
```

For removing the `notice` of line number 818 and 819 use `isset()`

```
if(isset($_POST['prtc_search']))
{

$list['result'] = $this->search_model->prtc_search($_POST['prtc_search']);
$list['searchquery']=$_POST['prtc_search'];
}else{
$list['result']="";
$list['searchquery']="";

}
```

Comment: You want to return `query result`or `$count`. I am bit confuse here

Comment: it should return the query results. Actually I get the results, I just want to get rid of those error/warnings from the page

Comment: have you check my answer??

Comment: tried your suggestion, it do not seem to remove the warnings.

Comment: I tried your suggestion. I still get the warning `Message: Undefined index from line number 819 and 818` line number 818 and 819 are these two lines `$list['result']= ` `$this->search_model->prtc_search($_POST['prtc_search']);`
`$list['searchquery']=$_POST['prtc_search'];`

Comment: @Karma you one problem is resolved now. And check updated answer for 819 and 818

Answer (score 0):

In Database query Part

function prtc_search($searchquery)
    {
        $count = 0;

```
    //Search using id
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->order_by('name ASC');
    $this->db->where("id LIKE '%$searchquery%'");
    $result = $this->db->get('prtc_info');
    if ($result->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        $row = $result->result_array();
        $count = 1;
        return $result;
    }
    else{
         return NULL;
     }
```

And for view.php:

```
       if($result != NULL and count($result)){
               //write code for result
       }
       else{
           // No record found
       }
```

Comment: I will give it a try @Amit Jha, Thanks for the response